# How can I strip progress bar to max 100%?

Tags: php, html, css

I have problem with progress bar in this code:

```
<div style='width: 100%;' class='serverlist_progress ipsBadge ipsBadge_small ipsBadge_neutral ipsResponsive_hideTablet ipsResponsive_hidePhone'>
    <div class='serverlist_progress-bar' style='width: {$allServerStats['amount_fill_servers']}; background: #3498db'></div>
    <div class='ipsType_center' style='position: absolute; width: 100%;'>
        {lang="sl_fill_servers"}: {$allServerStats['amount_fill_servers']}
    </div>
</div>
```

Sometime's my server show over 100% in progress bar.

How can I strip it to max 100%?

[image]

Comment: Don't mix width with padding or border or margins... Check for that.

Comment: Add the PHP that calculates the percentage.

Answer (score 0):

You use `position: absolute` and `width: 100%` gives you not that 100% what you need. You need to change `absolute` to `relative`. I think that your positioning will be broken after that, so then you need to correct existing styles.